# Can't access property object React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, rendering

I'm a beginner in React and I'm facing a problem that I can't solve.
I get an object from an API call.
In my console log, it appears well. I am able to access first-level properties (like ID for example) but if I want to access ACF values for example I get the error:

> TypeError: can't access property "date_project", this.state.projet.acf is undefined

I guess I don't do correctly to get the data from the ACF object but I don't understand how to do otherwise.

Here's my code:

```js
[import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.scss';
import {Row, Container, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {Config} from '../config';
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class Projet extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      projet: \[\]
    };
 }

 async componentDidMount() {
  const id = parseInt(this.props.match.params.id);
  const response = await fetch(Config.apiUrl + `wp-json/wp/v2/projet/${id}`);
  const json = await response.json();
  this.setState({ projet: json });
}

renderProjet() {
  console.log('projet', this.state.projet)
  return (
    <p>{this.state.projet.acf.date_projet}</p>
  )
}

  render() {
    return (
      <Container fluid className="App-home">
        <Row className="align-items-left">
          <div>
            { this.renderProjet()}
          </div>
        </Row>
       </Container>
    )
  }
}

export default (Projet);][1]
```

[image: Error]
[image: Object]

Comment: I think, You must define state project type objects, like this:  this.state = { projet: {}}; after that   you can watch result of JSON through   console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.projet)) . If you send Json Result I can help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of asynchronous call. When its trying to access `acf` at that time it is not available. Either create loading variable to track it or do not render component if data is not available:

```
render() {
    if(!this.state.projet?.acf) return null; //Do not render if data is not available
    return (
      <Container fluid className="App-home">
        <Row className="align-items-left">
          <div>
            { this.renderProjet()}
          </div>
        </Row>
       </Container>
    )
  }
```